# What is the difference between OnActionExecuting and beginexecute methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I have some custom code placed on BeginExecute method because I need to execute some logic before any action method is executed on any controller. I have seen that BeginExecute is often being executed automatically without interacting with the application. So this generates a lot of network traffic.

So I have decided to move my logic from BeginExecute to OnActionExecuting but I would like to know what is the difference between both methods in order to decide if this is the correct place where to put my logic.

Is OnActionExecuting being called every time BeginExecute is?

All my controlers in my MVC app inherit from MyController class.

First I had below code:

```
namespace My.Controls
{
   public partial class MyController : Controller
   {
       protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
       {
           IAsyncResult result = base.BeginExecute(requestContext, callback, state);
           // my logic here. Access to db to get information of the person currently logged in.
              
           return result;
       }
   }
}
```

Now I have replaced it by the following:

```
namespace My.Controls
{
   public partial class MyController : Controller
   {
       protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
       {
           base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

           // my logic here. Access to db to get information of the person currently logged in.
       }
   }
}
```

My problem is that BeginExecute is often called even if no one is using the application. For example, if I open my app in a browser tab and I leave it open without doing nothing, I have noticed that BeginExecute is often called from time to time. I have tried to debug it to know what it is the culprit. I have put a breakpoint inside BeginExecute but the only information I get from call stack is a line that says External Code and then the first call is BeginExecute. Is there any way to know what is exactly the "External code" which is calling BeginExecute?

I thought that maybe something in the background is generating requests without calling any action in controller so I decided to move that piece of code from BeginExecute to OnActionExecuting in order to that code get executed only before calling any action method in the controller. So my doubt is: all calls to BeginExecute always get through OnActionExecuting? or not necessarily?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills It is difficult to post here all my code and also to explain what is happening in my concrete scenario. Anyway I have updated my post and described more in details what is my problem.

Comment: Yep - hence why we asked for a _minimal_ example (not all of the code).

Comment: Do you have ajax calls using timer or something? That may be reason why filter is  executing without actually interacting with website? write log  in each filter method  and check how actually filter is working? you will understand events of it.